# Change language on asp.net error messages - exceptions

Tags: asp.net

I have a lot of web-sites on a virtual server (2008 R2) in Germany.
When there's an error on a site the error message is in German :(

I don't have any .net language packs installed on the server, but in the folder

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

I have both \1033 (English)  and \1031 (German)

And the same goes for the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5

I have tried to remove the \1031 folder, but that didn't help.

I would like a solution that don't involve web.config because the sites are used for ASP.NET training.

Answer (score 0):

Set the language of your web sites explicitly. Otherwise it keeps getting the language from the server, which is, as you've already said, in Germany... 
That should eliminate these problems completely.

Comment: <globalization fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" culture="da-US" uiCulture="da-US"/>  

That gives errors like this: Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: Der Name "projektklasse" ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.

Comment: And it would be nice not to have to set the language on each site.

Comment: @ThorOstergaard Well, if you have multiple websites, you have basically two options I know of: 1.) Put globalization to their web.configs, 2.) ask the provider of your hosting, if he can change the settings for you globally. Not really sure if there's any other way, because it's the way asp.net works by default. Even though you can change it, you would still need to change it for every website. Maybe if someone else can provide an alternative solution, but I'm sceptical...

Answer (score 0):

Steps to take:

1. Open CMD as administrator
2. type `LPKSETUP` and hit enter
3. and then uninstall the language that    is causing the issue.